# Dynamically creating Tables with while loop SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, dynamic-sql

I am creating tables dynamically with a while loop. There will be a number of tables created.  However, I am getting this error when I run the code.

> 'Conversion Failed when converting the varchar value'

Not sure why, because, if I hardcode the table name in, it works okay.

OLD CODE-

```
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PayComponents) --This is how many 
times im going to loop.
DECLARE @Pcomp INT = '1' --starting at 1
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(10) = 'Pcomp' --Part of the table name
DECLARE @TableNo VARCHAR(10) --declaring for adding onto table name.
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(10) --declare to hold full table name

 WHILE @Pcomp <= @Count --while 1 is less than or = to 61 loop
  BEGIN 
  DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @TableNo = CAST(@Pcomp AS VARCHAR(10))
  SET @TableName = @Table + @TableNo --Full table name... Pcomp1, Pcomp2, 
  Pcomp3, Pcomp4 etc


   SET @str = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.' + @TableName + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL //This is where i am getting the conversion error
   Drop Table ' + @TableName + '

   CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '
   (
   EeID INT,
   EeRef VARCHAR(10),
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   PayCompID SMALLINT,
   PayCompDesc VARCHAR(50),
   RateLastMonth MONEY,
   RateThisMonth MONEY
   )

   INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (EeID, EeRef, Name, PayCompID, 
   PayCompDesc, 
   RateLastMonth)
   SELECT
   ed.EeID,
   ed.EeRef,
   CONCAT(Forename, '' '', Surname) AS ''Name'',
   eec.PCompID,
   eec.PCDescr,
   eec.Rate
   FROM EeDetails ed
   INNER JOIN UnityEeComponents eec ON eec.EeRef = ed.EeRef
   CROSS JOIN PayrollRuns pr
   WHERE eec.PCompID = ' + @Pcomp + ' AND pr.RunID = (SELECT RunID FROM 
   PayrollRuns WHERE RunDate = ''2019-04-30'')
   ORDER BY ed.EeID

   UPDATE ' + @TableName + '
   SET 
   ' + @TableName + '.RateThisMonth = EeComponents.ECRate
   FROM ' + @TableName + '
   INNER JOIN 
   EeComponents
   ON 
   ' + @TableName +'.EeID = EeComponents.EeID
   WHERE EeComponents.PCompID = ' + @Pcomp + ' AND EeComponents.RunID = 
   (SELECT RunID FROM PayrollRuns WHERE RunDate = ''2019-02-08'')

   SET ' + @Pcomp + ' = ' + @Pcomp + ' + 1;'
   END;
```

NEW CODE - States that the 'Commads have completed successfully completed'

No tables are created though.

```
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PayComponents) --This is how many 
times im going to loop
DECLARE @Pcomp INT = '1' --starting at 1
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(10) = 'PComp' --Part of the table name
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(10) --declare to hold full table name

WHILE @Pcomp <= @Count --while 1 is less than or = to 61 loop
BEGIN
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str = '
SET ' + @TableName + ' = CONCAT('+@Table+', '+CAST(@Pcomp AS VARCHAR(10))+')
IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
Drop Table ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '

CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
(
EeID INT,
EeRef VARCHAR(10),
Name VARCHAR(50),
PayCompID SMALLINT,
PayCompDesc VARCHAR(50),
RateLastMonth MONEY,
RateThisMonth MONEY
)

INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' (EeID, EeRef, Name, PayCompID, 
PayCompDesc, RateLastMonth, RateThisMonth)
SELECT
ed.EeID,
ed.EeRef,
CONCAT(Forename, '' '', Surname),
eec.PCompID,
eec.PCDescr,
eec.Rate,
''0.00''
FROM EeDetails ed
INNER JOIN UnityEeComponents eec ON eec.EeRef = ed.EeRef
CROSS JOIN PayrollRuns pr
WHERE eec.PCompID = ' + QUOTENAME(@Pcomp) + ' AND pr.RunID = (SELECT RunID 
FROM PayrollRuns WHERE RunDate = ''2019-04-30'')
ORDER BY ed.EeID

UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
SET 
' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '.RateThisMonth = EeComponents.ECRate
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
INNER JOIN 
EeComponents
ON 
' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +'.EeID = EeComponents.EeID
WHERE EeComponents.PCompID = ' + CAST(@Pcomp AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' AND 
EeComponents.RunID = (SELECT RunID FROM PayrollRuns WHERE RunDate = ''2019- 
02-08'');'

EXEC (@str)
SET @Pcomp = CAST(@Pcomp AS VARCHAR(10)) + 1;
END;
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Careful, what you have there is wide open to injection. You should be quoting your object names, and parametrising your parameters. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql). Also, the reason you are getting the error is because you haven't parametrised your dynamic SQL. `{Non-numeric varchar} + {Integer} = Error: Cannot convert varchar value to integer`. Solve 3 problems at the same time; Quote your objects (`QUOTENAME`), and parametrise your query (which removes the error and removes injection).

Comment: @Larnu Just reading through that web article and thanks for you suggestions. Ill make the neccessary changes.. Always learning!

Comment: No worries, @Mark . If you do get stuck, please do post what you tried and I'll be happy to help, but (I think) I cover cover quite a lot in the linked article that should help you safely quote and parametrise you query. :)

Comment: If you parametrize your dynamic code, the problem with the invalid conversion goes away. Using QUOTENAME when assigning the value toe @TableName is also something that will keep you safe from SQL Injection.

Comment: @Larnu... Sorry to bother you again.. havent had a chance to look at this in a couple of days.. i have updated my code and it now states that the commands have completed successfully. i checked the DB and no new tables have been created. any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest posting new question with your new code, and explain the problem there

Answer (score 0):

The + operator does different things depending on the datatypes of the values it is applied to. It either performs a numeric operation (add) or it concatenates strings. You have (snippet)

```
'....SET ' + @Pcomp + ' = ' + @Pcomp + ' + 1;'
```

@Pcomp is an int. The other value is a string. What happens? To evaluate the result, the values must be converted into a single datatype in order to determine what to do. So which datatype is chosen? There are [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when your code does not explicitly indicate which to use - and strings have almost the lowest precedence. In this case, the engine attempts to convert your string literals to ints - which fails.

While that solves your immediate problem, you have much larger issues. Your loop is infinite because you don't increment your loop counter. In fact, you don't execute the dynamic query you generate. All fixable - but the larger question is why!

Why do you need to create separate tables here? You have a normalization issue that you should reconsider.

Lastly, you have hardcoded a very specific date into your query logic. While that may work for now, I cannot see how this will work in a generic, ongoing fashion.

Comment: I will be creating a c# winfroms application where the users get the results from all these tables. date can be selected. This is how the date will look when i get everything working <PRM.DATE.PRM> that will then be replaced with what the user selects in c# program.

Comment: They download the results from each table into one massice csv file. if there is a better way to acheive this then im all ears but im not sure lol...